# Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm (TDMA) aka Thomas Algorithm, using Python with NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I found an implementation of the thomas algorithm or TDMA in MATLAB.

```
function x = TDMAsolver(a,b,c,d)
    %a, b, c are the column vectors for the compressed tridiagonal matrix, d is the right vector
    n = length(b); % n is the number of rows

    % Modify the first-row coefficients
    c(1) = c(1) / b(1);    % Division by zero risk.
    d(1) = d(1) / b(1);    % Division by zero would imply a singular matrix.

    for i = 2:n-1
        temp = b(i) - a(i) * c(i-1);
        c(i) = c(i) / temp;
        d(i) = (d(i) - a(i) * d(i-1))/temp;
    end

    d(n) = (d(n) - a(n) * d(n-1))/( b(n) - a(n) * c(n-1));

    % Now back substitute.
    x(n) = d(n);
    for i = n-1:-1:1
        x(i) = d(i) - c(i) * x(i + 1);
    end
end
```

I need it in python using numpy arrays, here my first attempt at the algorithm in python.

```
import numpy

aa = (0.,8.,9.,3.,4.)
bb = (4.,5.,9.,4.,7.)
cc = (9.,4.,5.,7.,0.)
dd = (8.,4.,5.,9.,6.)

ary = numpy.array

a = ary(aa)
b = ary(bb)
c = ary(cc)
d = ary(dd)

n = len(b)## n is the number of rows

## Modify the first-row coefficients
c[0] = c[0]/ b[0]    ## risk of Division by zero.
d[0] = d[0]/ b[0]

for i in range(1,n,1):
    temp = b[i] - a[i] * c[i-1]
    c[i] = c[i]/temp
    d[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * d[i-1])/temp

d[-1] = (d[-1] - a[-1] * d[-2])/( b[-1] - a[-1] * c[-2])

## Now back substitute.
x = numpy.zeros(5)
x[-1] = d[-1]
for i in range(-2, -n-1, -1):
    x[i] = d[i] - c[i] * x[i + 1]
```

They give different results, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this since none of the online implementations for python actually work. I've tested it against built-in matrix inversion and the results match.

Here `a = Lower Diag`, `b = Main Diag`, `c = Upper Diag`, `d = solution vector`

```
import numpy as np

def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
    n = len(d)
    w= np.zeros(n-1,float)
    g= np.zeros(n, float)
    p = np.zeros(n,float)
    
    w[0] = c[0]/b[0]
    g[0] = d[0]/b[0]

    for i in range(1,n-1):
        w[i] = c[i]/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    for i in range(1,n):
        g[i] = (d[i] - a[i-1]*g[i-1])/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    p[n-1] = g[n-1]
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        p[i-1] = g[i-1] - w[i-1]*p[i]
    return p
```

For an easy performance boost for large matrices, use numba! This code outperforms `np.linalg.inv()` in my tests:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit    

@jit
def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
    n = len(d)
    w= np.zeros(n-1,float)
    g= np.zeros(n, float)
    p = np.zeros(n,float)
    
    w[0] = c[0]/b[0]
    g[0] = d[0]/b[0]

    for i in range(1,n-1):
        w[i] = c[i]/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    for i in range(1,n):
        g[i] = (d[i] - a[i-1]*g[i-1])/(b[i] - a[i-1]*w[i-1])
    p[n-1] = g[n-1]
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        p[i-1] = g[i-1] - w[i-1]*p[i]
    return p
```

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one difference between the two:

```
for i in range(1,n,1):
```

in Python iterates from index 1 to the last index `n-1`, while

```
for i = 2:n-1
```

iterates from index `1` (zero-based) to the `last-1` index, since Matlab has one-based indexing.

Comment: Python's `range()` function doesn't include the last index, so in this case the `for` loop would stop after n-1.

Comment: @voithos: it does not include `n`, but `n-1` *is* the last index, since Python has zero-based indexing while Matlab is one-based.

Comment: Ah, good point. I think a key difference (which I failed to realize) is that Python's `range()` does not go through to the end index specified (which, as you say, is due to Python's indexing from 0), whereas Matlab's `x:X` syntax **does** go through the end index.

Answer (score 1):

Writing somthing like this in python is going to be really slow. You would be much better off using LAPACK to do the numerical heavy lifting and use python for everything around it. LAPACK is compiled so it will run much faster than python it is also much more higly optimised than it is feasible for most of us to match.

SciPY provides low level wrappers for LAPACK so that you can call it from python very simply, the one you are looking for can be found here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgtsv.html#scipy.linalg.lapack.dgtsv

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, the Matlab version iterates over the second through second-to last elements. To do the same in Python, you want:

```
for i in range(1,n-1):
```

(As noted in voithos's comment, this is because the range function excludes the last index, so you need to correct for this in addition to the change to 0 indexing).